# Accessing a private function from my view in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Originally I had working code where I attached my function to the scope so that the variable could be accessed from my view. However, I was given some feedback that it would be better (and preferred) to set this to a private function since the only property I'm referencing in the template is just the id. Reason being there are already far too many functions attached to the scope which is making the app heavier than it needs to be.

Question is do I need to attach the actual property itself to the scope in order to access it from the view? I understand that `$scope.` is what makes a function accessible in the view, but I'm still unclear about how private functions work. Here is my code:

```
# private function inside controller
setCurrentOrderId = () ->
  now = moment().format("YYYY-MM")
  currentOrder = (_.find($scope.orders, (order) -> moment(order.scheduled_at).format("YYYY-MM") == now)) || {}
  $scope.currentOrderId = currentOrder.id

// view
<a ng-if="currentOrderId" href="/admin/orders/{{currentOrderId}}">
  <p class="center-text">Adjust Add-Ons</p>
</a>
```

** `setCurrentOrderId()` is being called inside a previously defined scope upon init() in case you were wondering how that's being set

I guess I'm unclear on whether or not setting `currentOrderId` to the $scope keeps the function private - maybe I'm being too dense about this. Also still trying to fully understand coffeescript - and true js for that matter (I'm better with ruby and node)

Comment: i think if you just assign the function to a variable, and not as a property of some object, then it is private.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up going with the code above and it was perfectly fine. So to summarize, the function above is still private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having already pushed this code up and seeing it live in production, can confirm that the function is still private